# Java: xmlpull giving me compile error (http://www.xmlpull.org/)

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm learning xml parsing and I would like to use the api from xmlpull.org.

I've downloaded from http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/download/ the "xmlpull_1_0_5.jar" file and included it in my reference library.

then wrote the following code (in Eclipse):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

public class Collections {
    public static void main (String args[])
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
        {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            System.out.println("parser implementation class is "+xpp.getClass());


        }

}
```

the problem is that when I compile I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: could not load any factory class (even small or full default implementation); nested exception is: 
    org.kxml2.io.XmlReader
    at org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(XmlPullParserFactory.java:225)
    at org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(XmlPullParserFactory.java:76)
    at Collections.main(Collections.java:12)

how come, please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So first of all, that is not a compiler error, as it doesn't happen at compile time. It's a runtime error.

The reason for the error is that xmlpull is an api only - it requires an appropriate xml pull parser implementation.

As their main page says,

> How To Use It?
>
> XMLPULL API is available freely. You can download XmlPull API as
>   tarball or zip file. We are also providing access to the latest API
>   version via anonymous CVS.
>
> However to use XMLPULL you will need download an implementation of
>   XmlPull API.

See http://www.xmlpull.org/impls.shtml#xmlpull for implementations that you can download.

Comment: What is an implementation, the only implementation I know is interface inplementation?

Comment: I'll try KXML2, sould I inclide the jar file as a reference library?  http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxml/files/kxml2/kxml2-min-2.3.0.jar

Comment: Yes, XmlPull defines an interface, and libraries like KXML2 implement that interface. It's a bit different from compile-time interfaces, though - it's actually runtime delegation. And yes, you should download the KXML2 jar file, and add it to your classpath at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for you help but I still get the same runtime error. at this link you can see the screen capture and libraries included: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8105bb1e41fbef0a&id=8105BB1E41FBEF0A%21104&authkey=!AEPdn2S4bhJ36LU

Comment: While KXML2 is J2ME - based, it should work, but since you're not doing J2ME development, try XPP3/MXP1 at http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/mxp1/ instead

Comment: I've included xpp3_xpath-1.1.4b.jar and then tried with xpp3_xpath-1.1.4c.jar downloaded from http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/dist/java-repository/xpp3/jars/ , but still it doesn't work. I've uploaded screen capture with the usual message xmlpaull_error_03.JPG.

Comment: ok, so I downloaded the 2 jar files (xmlpull_1_0_5.jar and xpp3_xpath-1.1.4c.jar), compiled your code, and ran it with those 2 jar files on the classpath. Using the command-line `java -cp .:./xmlpull_1_0_5.jar:./xpp3-1.1.4c.jar Collections` (on OS X - if you're using windows, change the ':' path separator to ';', and I got the result `parser implementation class is class org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParserCachingStrings` So, the only explanation that I can think of is that you are not setting the classpath properly

Comment: Ok finally I've solved the issue, basically according to XPP3 site, the API implementation jar file includes the API and the API implementation. Including in the build path the API and the API implementation creates an error, only the API implementation should be included since, according to the site: "the jar file contains BOTH parser implementation and XMLPULL API". Thanks for your help